# Correct way to end ssh tunnel

Tags: macos, ssh, zsh, ssh-tunnel

I frequently need to connect to a database instance on AWS, so I use an SSH tunnel.  I can create one with the following command:

```
ssh -N -L 12345:some-database.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 admin@bastion.company.com
```

This works great.  However, when I want to disconnect, my only option seems to be <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, which results in:

```
^Z[1]  + 12656 suspended
```

If I try to use port 12345 again, it says it's already in use.  I have to kill the suspended process with:

```
lsof -t -i:12345 | xargs kill -9
```

This seems like a hassle.  Is there a more convenient way to properly shut down an SSH tunnel when I'm done using it?  Thanks!

Comment: In Linux I would expect Ctrl+c to terminate `ssh`; and it does work. I don't know macOS though. Do you run `ssh` in a way that makes it ignore SIGINT? And maybe some other signals? Is this the reason you use `kill -9` instead of sole `kill`? Or do you reconfigure the tty, so Ctrl+c is not special?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: He's using CTRL+Z which apparently does the same as in Linux to suspend the process, but he's not using CTRL+C. The `exit` command might close the tunnel.

Comment: @harrymc Well, my first comment was meant to be a polite equivalent of "why on Earth don't you use Ctrl+c for this?".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski / @harrymc Hah, ok you two are completely correct I'm an idiot.  The answer is because I had `CTRL+C` bound to a custom keyboard shortcut and it was blocking the _normal_ behavior.  Posted my answer, but honestly it's just because I'm stupid and should stop using Macs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help!  I figured this out, and it's mainly because I'm stupid.

Those who commented above as to why I'm not using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> are on to something.  The answer is basically, "Well I tried and nothing happened".

I just figured ssh didn't support that, but I decided to dig in a bit more.  Ok, so why does nothing happen?

The answer to that is because I'm using the [Warp terminal](https://www.warp.dev/), and had <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> bound to the "Copy" command because I use Windows and Linux a lot, and prefer this to the MacOS <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. It seems that this was blocking the default `^C` handler.

I've decided to just change back to the default keyboard shortcuts in Warp and the problem went away.

Comment: I guess if you instead defined a keyboard shortcut that sends `^C`, i.e. ASCII ETX, a byte `0x03`, then you could use the new shortcut to interrupt commands. The magic that "translates" `^C` to SIGINT is implemented deeper; on the level of Warp you just need to pass the byte.

Comment: Yea, the feature that Warp needs is to ignore the keyboard binding if there's no actual text selected.  I've logged a bug on this issue.